# Ejabberd webadmin access timeout

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I just installed ejabberd on a remote server.
Let's say remote server's ip is `123.123.123.123`, and its internal ip address is `10.0.0.10`.

Then, I edited:

## `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg`

```
%% ... more codes
%% Options which are set by Debconf and managed by ucf

%% Admin user
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "myexample.com"}}.

%% Hostname
{hosts, ["myexample.com"]}.

%% ... more codes
{5280, ejabberd_http, [
                         %%{request_handlers,
                         %% [
                         %%  {["pub", "archive"], mod_http_fileserver}
                         %% ]},
                         %%captcha,
                         http_bind,
                         http_poll,
                         web_admin
                        ]}
%% ... more codes
```

and, added `admin` as admin user by executing the following in the ssh at the server `123.123.123.123`:

```
root:# ejabberdctl register admin myexample.com adminpassword
root:# service ejabberd restart
```

## THINGS NOT WORKING:

However, the admin console `myexample.com:5280/admin` is unreachable (timeout). I've also tried `123.123.123.123:5280/admin`, but failed.

## THINGS WORKING:

However, from server's console, if I access `10.0.0.10:5280/admin`, it works. Also, I can confirm the user `admin` is registered by executing the following:

```
ejabberdctl registered_users
```

## QUESTION:

How do I make the access the webadmin (or more importantly, accessing any ports from its external ip or domain) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be just a connectivity problem.
This is what I'd do:

1. 'sudo netstat -nap | grep 5280' (or equivalent) to verify on which interfaces ejabberd is listening for webadmin
2. If it's listening on "all" (0.0.0.0) as I expect, then verify its reachability with something like 'telnet 123.123.123.123 5280'. If it can't connect, then check the server's firewall (e.g. 'sudo iptables -L -n -v').

You probably just need to "open" 123.123.123.123:5280 for the source host you're connecting from.

Comment: Thanks! The external ip's port 5280 was closed. Opening the port simply solved the problem!